# How to set the starting directory (using uigetfile in Matlab) to 'Computer'?

Tags: matlab, directory

I made a Matlab GUI. I would like to set the dialog box for input file to be by default set to 'Computer' directory. I know how to change the default path (`[FileName PathName] = uigetfile('D:\Applications\Matlab6p5\work\*.m;*.mdl;*.mat','MATLAB Files');`), but I don't know what is the name of the path in case of 'Computer' (directory where all server and local disc names are listed). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a directory `My Computer.{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}` that links to the node "My computer" (see [this answer on SU](https://superuser.com/a/499658))- you can do the same with other "special folders" - see e.g. the comment by @thewaywewalk.
2. Use this directory as the start path for `uigetfile`.

Thus:

```
tmpLinkToMyComputer = fullfile(tempDir,'MyComputer.{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}');
mkdir(tmpLinkToMyComputer);
uigetfile(fullfile(tmpLinkToMyComputer,'*.m;*.mdl;*.mat'),'MATLAB Files')
```

Comment: That is great! Wouldn't have thought it's possible. Also you could do the same with the standard user profile with `{450D8FBA-AD25-11D0-98A8-0800361B1103}`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It did solve my problem. Temporal directory in matlab is tEmpdir and one slash was missing. Corrected code: tmpLinkToMyComputer = fullfile(tempDir,'MyComputer.{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}');
mkdir(tmpLinkToMyComputer);
uigetfile([tmpLinkToMyComputer,'\*.m;*.mdl;*.mat'],'MATLAB Files')

Comment: @user3410021: thanks for pointing out the issues, and for asking a very interesting question!